# Show images under each other with text at right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sorry if this seems like a overasked question, but mine is a bit different and I'm needing some help here.

So, i got 2 images : A and B. I want them to be displayed under each other, and I need to put text at the right of images A and B.

Now, the problem is that I can ONLY put the text after putting the images A and B. Here is an example :

```
<img src="A.jpg">
<img src="B.jpg">

<p> Text of A, at the right of A </p>
<p> Text of B, at the right of B </p>
```

I can't put the text after image A for some reasons, and I don't know how to proceed this way.

Thanks for the help !

P.S : I'm looking for a clean version, not something with a position:absolute making a big mess when the user resize for example.

Comment: why not create two divs and place an image and paragraph in each one

Comment: Well because I'm using some javascript, and I need the text to be in the same script, I can't separate them.

Comment: You're better off making a snippet of what you're currently doing. Too difficult to understand what you mean by the text needing to be in the same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `flex`

```css
#wrapper img{
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}
div#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
div#wrapper img:nth-child(1n){
 order: 1;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
div#wrapper img:nth-child(2){
 order: 3;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
div#wrapper p:nth-child(3n){
 order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
div#wrapper p:nth-child(4n){
 order: 4;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg" alt="">
    <p> Text of A, at the right of A </p>
    <p> Text of B, at the right of B </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!